# How to update state of component with some data which is coming from reducer

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Lets say I have a subcategoryContainer.js which is passing props to subcategory.js now there is another component filter.js imported in subcategory.js. This filter.js is receiving props from subcategory.js. Data is coming from store. Here redux thunk is updating store asynchronously.

Now the problem is in putting props to state of filter.js. Initialy state is set to empty object. Even if I update state in componentWillReceiveProps method, I only get empty object in render() instead of updated state which should have data of props in it.

This is the order of methods fired.

```
1.render() // initial data from redux reducer//
2.componentWillReceiveProps()
3.render() // new data by redux thunk
```

Here at point 3 it seems componentWillReceiveProps() should also trigger but it is not.

How can I update filter.js state with newly received props (props->updated by thunk)

How should I do this. Please assist.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that `componentWillReceiveProps` is actually triggered? It triggers only when props actually change, not when the component is mounted initially and the props don't change. You probably don't want to initialize state to an empty state, but to something based on props already.

Comment: Yes. props are getting updated by redux thunk. So reducer will send initial state to filter.js first and redux thunk call a service now as new data comes reducer will again send data to filter.js. This is where I want to update the state of filter.js. But componentWillReceiveProps is triggering only one time. I added some line in question. Please visit.

Comment: I see, are you stuck on an old version of React? Actually `componentWillReceiveProps` has been deprecated in favor of https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops which is probably exactly what you need

Comment: Thanks @Tommos for hinting. This links tells the whole story and future planning of reactjs.
https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/03/27/update-on-async-rendering.html

Title:Update on Async Rendering-March 27, 2018 by Brian Vaughn